# Outlook Object Model ContactItem won't delete

Tags: outlook, out-of-memory, outlook-addin, outlook-object-model

I'm bedeviled by this.  I have a c# application that I need to have a backup before I modify my main contact.  But it seems that the copy, sticks around no matter what.  I'm verifying this by visual check at the contents of my contents folder in Outlook.

I have a simple test case like so...

```
Application outlookApplication = new Application();
NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("mapi");
outlookNamespace.Logon("", "", true, true);
MAPIFolder Folder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
MAPIFolder Folder2 = Folder.Folders["Test1"];
Items ContactItems = Folder2.Items;
foreach (ContactItem Contact in ContactItems)
{
    ContactItem Backup = (ContactItem)Contact.Copy();
    Backup.Delete();
    break;
}
outlookNamespace.Logoff();
outlookNamespace = null;
```

If I try to delete it twice, it causes an error.
Even tried moving it to the deleted items folder, but no luck.  Outlook 2010. What is going on?

EDIT: WORKAROUND: If I create a new contact and populate from the original, I can delete it just fine.

Comment: Hi JP, since I found my work-around, I haven't revisited this issue.  It's still on the back burner, just not a high priority.  When I check out the issue again, i'll try your answer and reply accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C# syntax, but I suspect it's because you are adding to the Items collection when you create the copy. I would do this:

Before the start of the foreach loop, check the count of ContactItems:

```
Items ContactItems = Folder2.Items;
' display ContactItems.Count here, is it Console.WriteLine(ContactItems.Count) ??
```

After creating the copy, check the ContactItems.Count again. If it has increased, then you need to change your loop to a "For i = ContactItems.Count to 1 Step -1" type of loop instead of a foreach loop (sorry, I only know the VB syntax, I don't know the equivalent C# syntax). It has to be a backwards loop.

If that doesn't work, then create a copy and add it to another Contacts folder, that way it won't interfere with the Items collection of the folder you are working with. That is similar to what you are already doing.